# how to display the selected date and time using react DateTime?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

i'm using react DateTime and i want to display or at least console the selected date and time so i could save it in a database later on

the input takes today's date and current hour as a initiale value and i can console it easily, but when i select an other day an exeption shows up.

there is a `useState` hook that i use to initialize the `date` variable

```
const [date,setDate] = useState(new Date() )
```

```
<Datetime   
    isValidDate={(current)=>{
        let today= new Date()
        return current.isAfter(today)
    }}  
    dateFormat="DD-MM-YYYY" 
    onChange={()=>setDate((e)=>e.target.value)} 
    value={date}> 
</Datetime>
```

Answer (score -1):

According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime, your `onChange` should be:
`onChange={(val) => setDate(val)}`. You get a `moment` date as input for `onChange`.

Furthermore, you get an exception because your current `onChange` is totally invalid:

1. It doesn't receive an event but the actual selected moment value.
2. Even it it was getting an event, the `e` should be coming from the `onChange` and not from the state setter:

`onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)}`.

Comment: it would also be great to init the state with a moment date to have a consistent state type

Comment: instead of a complete date this displays a  number like this one "1677057580642". what can i add?

Comment: @Abdelhamid Works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-pine-godkhk?file=/src/App.js.